# Web Application - Secure In A Password Protected Directory?

Tags: php, security

Is a php/mysql web application secure in a password protected folder on a (reputable) hosted server?

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Not if the person hacking you has your password.

Make sure your hosting provider is taking measures against hacking attempts, also that there are firewalls on their networks. I have read a tutorial about safe PHP Coding practices and it is awesome. Check it out:

http://www.addedbytes.com/php/writing-secure-php/

Good Luck.